# Entity Framework, TPT Inheritance and Multi-Language support

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

I have this DB Structure:

**Service**

- Id    int    PK
- CategoryId FK
- SomeOtherFields

**LocalizedService**

- LocalizedServiceId  PK
- LanguageId FK
- Name
- Description

As you can see, I have a base table called Service, and a LocalizedService table in which I'm writing multilingual data, such as name and description which should be translated in different languages. 
I have linked both tables in EF designer using TPT inheritance. Service is a base class of LocalizedService. The problem is that, TPT requires both tables to have primary key, which wouldn't be a problem if I was working on 1 language, but I should translate service rows across 3 different languages. So only LocalizedServiceId shouldn't be unique, but a combination of LocalizedServiceId + LanguageId should be unique because I can not insert more than one language row into LocalizedService. For example, take a look at LocalizedService rows bellow:

- 1, 1, SomeService, NULL <-- Inserted
- 2, 1, AnotherService, NULL <-- Inserted
- 2, 2, RussianTranslationService, NULL <-- can not insert because LocalizedServiceId with value 2 already exists in the table.

That's not a problem on DB side, I can create PK for multiple fields (for example, LocalizedServiceId and LanguageId both will be Primary Key), but in this case, EF designer throws errors saying:
"Error 13 Error 75: Key usage is not valid. uPay.Data.Entities.LocalizedServiceRecord cannot define keys because one of its base classes (uPay.Data.Entities.ServiceRecord) defines keys. D:\Projects\uPay\uPay.Data.Entities\Entities.edmx 1531 9 uPay.Data.Entities". I really need a solution on this problem ASAP, your help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error that you are getting from your EDM is coming from the fact that EF supports TPT inheritance between 2 entities on a one to one association which means a one to one relationship on database and that essentially requires that both tables has the very primary keys. Your scenario is essentially a one to many relationship where each service could have many localizations based on the ServiceID and LocalizationID. 

There are 2 workarounds that has been suggested by *Craig Stuntz* on his post [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564975/entity-framework-table-per-type-inheritance-existing-database) by the way, the first one is to drill down into the EDM's SSDL part and remove the LanguageId from the *Key* section:

```
<EntityType Name="ServiceTypeLocale">
   <Key>
       <PropertyRef Name="LocalizedServiceId" />
       <!-- You have to comment this:-->
       <!--<PropertyRef Name="LanguageId" />-->
   </Key>
...
```

This is not recommended by the way since if you do this then the *Update Model from Database* wizard will try to "fix" your mapping every time you do an update.

Another workaround would be to create a view in your database and simulate a one to one relationship and then map the view instead of the ServiceLocalization table.